# convert a text to another text with another structure

Tags: c++

I just want to write an code to change the input to another text with another structure.
for example a text is given. and I should convert them intoanother text like I say below.

this is the input :

```
typedef enum
{
    RED,
    GREEN,
    BLUE
} Color;
```

and this should be the output :

```
enum class Color
{
    RED = 0,
    GREEN = 1,
    BLUE = 2
};
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string example = "typedef enum {RED,GREEN,BLUE} Color;";
    string var_name;

    for(int i=0; i <example.size(); i++)
    {
        if(example[i] == ';') break;
        var_name += example[i];
    }
    //cout << var_name << endl;


   int i = var_name.length() - 1; // last character
   while (i != 0 && !isspace(var_name[i]))
   {
     --i;
   }
   string lastword = var_name.substr(i+1); // +1 to skip leading space
   cout << lastword << endl;
    ///////////////////////////////

    return 0;
}
```

I could only get the color. can anybody help me to complete this:)?
the enum of c is just a text and I have to convert it into an another text which look like an anum in c++. its just working with strings and charecters.

Comment: `enum class` was introduced to `C++11`. Regular `enum` is still valid in C++ so why you need to do something extra? It smells like in fact you need more like conversion of enumeration to a string and/or vice versa.

Comment: could you explain in more detail what you're trying to achieve? What do you want your program to print?

Comment: the enum of c is just a text and i have to convert it into an another text which look like an anum in c++. its just working with strings and charecters.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify this there (fix title too).

Comment: To clarify (and give a hint how to improve question): so basically you need to parse simplified C code (enums only) and generate string with C++ code containing respective definition of `enum class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string temp;
    vector <string> lines;
    while(true){
        getline(cin,temp);
        lines.push_back(temp);
        if(temp.back()==';')
            break;

    }

    cout<<"enum class "<<lines.back().substr(2,lines.back().size()-3)<<endl;
    cout<<lines[1]<<endl;
    for(int i=2 ; i<lines.size()-1 ; i++){
        if (i!=lines.size()-2){
            cout<<lines[i].substr(0,lines[i].size()-1)<<" = "<< i-2<< ","<<endl;
        }
        else
            cout<<lines[i]<<" =  "<< i-2<<endl;
    }
    cout <<"};";



}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).